# How do I copy data from a collection of objects to a collection of different objects in Java8

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I would like to use functional programming to copy data from a collection of one object to a collection of other objects.

I have been reading several Java 8 books and researching online. I am pretty sure I want to use stream(), but just about every example I have seen always iterates through a collection, does some processing on the objects in the collection, and uses println() to output the contents. No one seems to discuss how to deal with situations like the one described below.

1. Suppose we have the following objects:

   ```
   public class ObjectA
   {
       private String someData;
       private int moreData;

       public String getSomeData()
       {
          return someData;
       }

       public void setSomeData(String sData)
       {
          someData = sData;
       }

       public int getMoreData()
       {
          return moreData;
       }

       public void setMoreData(int mData)
       {
          moreData = mData;
       }
   }


   public class ObjectB
   {
      private String b_Data;

      public String getB_Data()
      {
         return b_Data;
      }

      public void setB_Data(String bData)
      {
         b_Data = bData;
      }
   }
   ```
2. I want to create a collection of ObjectB objects whose b_data atributes are equal to the someData attributes in a collection of ObjectAs.
3. A reasonably good way to do this is illustrated in the code below:

   ```
   public class Collector
   {
       public Collection<ObjectB> collectObjects(Collection<ObjectA> theAs)
       {
          // The use of an ArrayList is arbitrary. I might want to use any number
          // of different lists or even different collections!
          final Collection<ObjectB> theBs = new ArrayList<ObjectB>(); 

          for(ObjectA obj : theAs)
          {
              final ObjectB bobj = new ObjectB();
              bobj.setB_Data(obj.getSomeData());

              theBs.add(bobj);
          }

          return theBs;
      }
   }
   ```

The code in the `collectObjects()` method will work, but it uses techniqhes of imperative programming. I would like to know how to make the collection of ObjectBs using functional techniques.

Is there a way to accomplish this using streams and lambdas?

Answer (score 3):

This situation actually applies perfectly with the Stream API. What you want is to:

1. Make a `Stream<ObjectA>` which is a Stream of your input list, with [`theAs.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--).
2. Map each `ObjectA` in the Stream to an `ObjectB` with [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).
3. Collect the result with [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) into a new list using [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

This would be an implementation:

```
public Collection<ObjectB> collectObjects(Collection<ObjectA> theAs) {
    return theAs.stream().map(obj -> {
        final ObjectB bobj = new ObjectB();
        bobj.setB_Data(obj.getSomeData());
        return bobj;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Of course, you could create a constructor of `ObjectB` that takes `obj.getSomeData()` as parameter. It would simplify the code because then you could write:

```
public Collection<ObjectB> collectObjects(Collection<ObjectA> theAs) {
    return theAs.stream().map(obj -> new ObjectB(obj.getSomeData())).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`obj -> new ObjectB(obj.getSomeData())` is called a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
List<ObjectB> theBs = theAs
    .stream()
    .map(a-> {
        final ObjectB bobj = new ObjectB();
        bobj.setB_Data(a.getSomeData());
        return bobj;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `a -> { ... }` construct is a *lambda*, a construct that lets you pass some executable code into a method call.

The body of the lambda comes straight from the loop body in your second example.